# Erro ao carregar o chart do api da google no ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-api

Quando peguei o exemplo do site funcionou, porém quando incluo um novo Webform e em um novo projeto e colo os códigos do exemplo codebehind em VB.net e o código aspx não funciona, dá a mensagem de alerta, fiz alguma adaptações na coleta de 3 pontos para ficar mais fácil rodar o exemplo. Tem dias que tento. Podem ajudar?
Uso visualStudio Express 2017

aspx código:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" 
MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="teste1.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="SIIv3.teste1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'teste1.aspx/GetDadosGrafico',
            data: '{}',
            success:
            function (response) {
                drawchart(response.d);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Issue to load Data.");
            }
        });
    })
    function drawchart(dataValues) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Column Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Column Value');
        for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([dataValues[i].Silos, dataValues[i].Total]);
        }
        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartdiv')).
            draw(data, { title: "JcmSoft - Participação Mercado por País" });
    }
</script>



<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 590px; height: 201px;">
</div>


</asp:Content>
```

VB.net codebehind

```
Imports System.Web.Services

Partial Class teste1
Inherits Page


<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function GetDadosGrafico() As List(Of DadosDetalhes)
    Dim listaDados As New List(Of DadosDetalhes)()

    Dim details As New DadosDetalhes With {
        .Silos = "silo",
        .Total = 13
    }
    listaDados.Add(details)

    details = New DadosDetalhes With {
        .Silos = "silo1",
        .Total = 20
    }
    listaDados.Add(details)

    details = New DadosDetalhes With {
        .Silos = "silo2",
        .Total = 5
    }
    listaDados.Add(details)

    Return listaDados
End Function

End Class

Public Class DadosDetalhes
    Public Property Silos() As String
    Public Property Total() As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Se você estiver começando o projeto, e ele não estiver grande. Eu recomendo você passar a utilizar ASP.NET Core Razor Pages ou ASP.NET MVC, porque ASP.NET WebForms já está " depreciado" e não irá mais receber atualizações com novidades.

Comment: obrigado, vou tentar.

Comment: Se você usa apenas `visual basic`, então estuda sobre o `MVC`, pois `Razor Pages` tem suporte apenas a C#.

Comment: Pesquisei sobre a sua sugestão, mas achei muito complexo o uso do MVC, devemos ter um conhecimento muito alto para criação de controllers, views, tarefas e etc...O meu projeto é muito simples. Basicamente vou usar gridview e alguns gráficos coletando dados BD oracle, Por isso que optei pelo asp.net. Tem alguma sugestão de como criar webforms para IIS simplesmente arrastando os componentes? agradeço a sua ajuda.

Comment: Se você estiver utilizando o Visual Studio, quando você abre um arquivo `.aspx`, logo após o código, abaixo. Tem 3 botões, você pode clicar em "Design" e fazer da mesma maneira que se faz com Windows Forms: [Veja aqui uma imagem de exemplo.](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/creating-a-basic-web-forms-page/_static/image8.png)

Comment: boa noite, resolvi programar em asp.net mvc conforme a sua dica. No início foi difícil, mas estou pegando a manha. obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Que bom, parabéns! É difícil mesmo no inicio, tive bastante dificuldade, mas vale a pena :)